# How to handle the absence or expiration of bearer token in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET web API and I want to return a meaningful message instead of this exception in case if the *token* was expired or it wasn't provided in the request at all. This is the exception that I'm getting in this case.

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
        "StackTrace": "   at WebApi.Controllers.SomeController..ctor() in SomePath\\Controllers\\SomeController.cs:line 21\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
    }
}
```

I have tried like this and added a breakpoint, but it doesn't even reach it, so I'm not sure where should I write the code to handle this.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();
    if (actionContext == null)
    {
        actionContext.Response = jsonHelper.setHttpResponseMessage(jsonHelper.setResponse(false, null, "Expired or Incorrect token."));
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using Try/Catch?

Comment: The actual error has nothing to do with the code you posted. The message is that `SomeController` does not have a parameterless constructor so probably your DI is broken.

Comment: @PeterBons No, actually my controller does have a parameterless constructor & if I provide valid token, I get proper results

Comment: @bsod_Yes but I think that the exception happens somewhere before it reach this method, the breakpoint doesn't even fire although I have added it at the very beginning of the method.

Comment: It appears this is where the error is occurring 'SomePath\Controllers\SomeController.cs:line 21'  What does this line look like?

Comment: @MarkWagoner This line is basically retrieving a value from _Claims_ `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("SomeValue").Value` and assigning it to a variable in the cotroller & since there was no token provided, it through the exception. But the fact that it reached that line, that must mean that `OnAuthorization` method got executed, isn't it?

Comment: Have you made custom Authorize attribute?

Comment: Why cant you use the Authorize Attribute? Are you using JWT ?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Yes, I extended the Authorize attribute in order to write some custom code like the one in my question `public override void OnAuthorization`. Anyway, I have solved it thanks to Mark comment

Comment: @zetawars I'm using it, kindly check my above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark Wagoner comment, I saw this sentence in the exception which I didn't notice before

> in SomePath\Controllers\SomeController.cs:line 21

In the controller in line 21, there is this line:

```
    ...    
    string variable = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("SomeValue").Value;

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
    ...
```

And since the token wasn't provided here, then it's to be expected that the above line would through *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* exception. I declared it outside the method because it is used in multiple methods. So, I removed it from there & declared it for each method and that solved my problem.

The thing that I didn't know is that the variables that I declare in the controller outside of the methods are declared first, then it starts executing the code in custom authorize `CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute` class.